# Can't find the cause of a 'missing right parenthesis' error

Tags: oracle, view, sqlplus, ora-00907

I am having problems with a line of code.  I am trying to create a count function for a view that I created.  I have done this a bunch of different ways but below is the format that I have most recently used.

```
CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, COUNT(RIDERS) AS
SELECT EVENTNAME, RACES.DESCRIPTION, 
       RIDERS_FIRSTNAME||' '||RTRIM(RIDERS_LASTNAME)
FROM EVENTS, RACES, PARTICIPATION, RIDERS
WHERE EVENTS.EVENTID = RACES.EVENTID
AND RACES.RACEID = PARTICIPATION.RACEID
AND RIDERS.RIDERID = PARTICIPATION.RIDERID
ORDER BY RIDERS.RIDERS_LASTNAME, EVENTNAME;
```

The error I am getting is `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`. The error is at the `(COUNT(RIDERS)` part of the code.  Any ideas how I should tackle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of names in parentheses on line 1 should be the names of the view columns:

```
CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, COUNT(RIDERS) AS ...
```

You can't create a column called "COUNT(RIDERS" or even "COUNT(RIDERS)" since a column name may not contain ( or ).  This would work:

```
CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, RIDER_FULL_NAME) AS ...
```

However it appears that you really do want a count of something, though I'm not sure of what.  To do that the view definition would have to be something like:

```
CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, RIDER_COUNT) AS
SELECT EVENTNAME, RACES.DESCRIPTION, COUNT(*)
FROM EVENTS, RACES, PARTICIPATION, RIDERS
WHERE EVENTS.EVENTID = RACES.EVENTID
AND RACES.RACEID = PARTICIPATION.RACEID
AND RIDERS.RIDERID = PARTICIPATION.RIDERID
GROUP BY EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION;
```

(i.e. the COUNT function goes in the SELECT part, not in the list of column names).

As an aside, since you are presumably new to Oracle, I would suggest you start using the more modern ANSI join syntax to make your queries clearer:

```
...
FROM EVENTS
JOIN RACES ON RACES.EVENTID = EVENTS.EVENTID
JOIN PARTICIPATION ON PARTICIPATION.RACEID = RACES.RACEID
JOIN RIDERS ON RIDERS.RIDERID = PARTICIPATION.RIDERID
```

Comment: I suppose I am still doing something wrong...   I am getting an, ORA-00937: not a single-group group function,  error  the code I am using is..

    CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, RIDER_COUNT) AS
    SELECT EVENTNAME, RACES.DESCRIPTION, COUNT(RIDERS_LASTNAME)
    FROM EVENTS, RACES, PARTICIPATION, RIDERS
    WHERE EVENTS.EVENTID = RACES.EVENTID
    AND RACES.RACEID = PARTICIPATION.RACEID
    AND RIDERS.RIDERID = PARTICIPATION.RIDERID;
    ORDER BY EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION;

Comment: I suppose I am still doing something wrong... I am getting an, ORA-00937: not a single-group group function, error the code I am using is.. 


CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, RIDER_COUNT) AS SELECT EVENTNAME, RACES.DESCRIPTION, COUNT(RIDERS_LASTNAME) FROM EVENTS, RACES, PARTICIPATION, RIDERS WHERE EVENTS.EVENTID = RACES.EVENTID AND RACES.RACEID = PARTICIPATION.RACEID AND RIDERS.RIDERID = PARTICIPATION.RIDERID; ORDER BY EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION;

Comment: Yes, you haven't got a GROUP BY clause in the query.  Se my example that does.

Comment: Thanks - I will modify and try again.

Comment: Tony thanks that seemed to work very well. I also appreciate the example in how to use standardized syntax for joining tables.

Comment: I should have known that you can't create a function on a view you are creating......

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, COUNT(RIDERS) AS
```

....

Should not it be:

```
CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, COUNT(RIDERS)) AS
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message points out you are missing a closing bracket ). The bracket is opened here : 'ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME' and is never closed.

Comment: Oh my god!  You mean the error message was correct?  Who would have thought!

Answer (score 1):

you can't have brackets in column names unless you put quotation marks around. Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, "COUNT(RIDERS)") AS ...
```

or

```
CREATE VIEW ERP_REPORT(EVENTNAME, DESCRIPTION, COUNT_RIDERS) AS ...
```

For example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW foo ("count(*)") AS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dual;

View created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW foo (count_all) AS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dual;

View created
```

Comment: Vencent I tried this and could only get it to count the Count_Riders column and would not display the rest of the columns.

Comment: @Michael: you mean when you query `SELECT * FROM erp_report` you only see one column ?

Comment: Yes, when I SELECT * erp_report  ..  I am new at this so I may not have followed your instructions correctly.  I will run it again just you you provided.  I am going to go with the second option.  the run the two separate sets of code.

Answer (score 1):

As Tony points out there are actually several syntax errors in your statement.  The missing bracket is just the first.

I find it useful to have an IDE which supports bracket matching, because it can be hard to walk back through the code and find which bracket lacks a mate.  As it happens my choice is [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com) but just about anything which is more advanced than NotePad ought to be able to do this.